# haskell parallel multithread a do block

Tags: multithreading, list, haskell, multiprocessing

How do you multithread this code:

```hs
-- k: length of partition desired
-- n: number to make partitions from
integer_partitions :: Int -> Int -> [[Int]]
integer_partitions 0 _ = []
integer_partitions 1 n = [[n]]
integer_partitions k n =
  do x <- [1..n - k + 1]
     map (x:) (integer_partitions (k - 1) (n - x))
integer_partitions_par k n =
  do x <- [1..n - k + 1]
     map (x:) (integer_partitions (k - 1) (n - x))

variation_models ncars nlocations =
  filter (both_conditions (adds_up_to nlocations) num_orderedq) $
  integer_partitions ncars nlocations
```

I figured multithreading only the top would be the best, but we will see after testing

Comment: Sorry to edit after receiving answers, but I thought that my small scoping of the problem may not be where the threading needs to occure (if it can be usefully be put anywhere)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to parallelise pure code is with [`Control.Parallel.Strategies`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parallel-3.2.2.0/docs/Control-Parallel-Strategies.html). The first thing you can try is `parMap rdeepseq` instead of `map`, which creates a green thread for each element individually, or `parListChunk n rdeepseq` to use a chunk size of `n` with sequential evaluation within the chunks. Here I use `parMap` to replace the *outer* mapping provided by the `do` notation, not the inner map that just prepends each `x` to the recursive call.

```
integer_partitions_par :: Int -> Int -> [[Int]]
integer_partitions_par 0 _ = []
integer_partitions_par 1 n = [[n]]
integer_partitions_par k n = concat $ parMap rdeepseq
  (\ x -> map (x:) (integer_partitions_par (k - 1) (n - x)))
  [1..n - k + 1]
```

It usually takes some tweaking to balance the parallelism benefit with its overhead, and I haven’t looked at all into where your algorithm would actually benefit from parallelism. [Parallel and Concurrent Programming in Haskell](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/parallel-and-concurrent/9781449335939/) has a great introduction to this library.

You do need to build the program with `-threaded` and invoke it with `+RTS -N` to pass the `-N` flag to the RTS (that is, the GHC runtime system) to inform it to use a number of OS threads equal to the number of cores (or hyperthreads) available on the hardware you’re running on. The runtime scheduler maps lightweight Haskell sparks or green threads onto the available heavyweight system threads.